# Compare negative with positive, ignoring sign

Tags: comparator, negative

I need to compare a negative voltage with a positive one, each on the order of a few hundred millivolts each; I want to compare the magnitudes, ignoring the signs, although only for this particular quadrant (I don't need all other signs.) How can I do it? I thought of using resistors to pull the negative voltage positive, but it only gives me a small signal on top of a DC offset, and that is difficult to compare with.

Comment: I wrote [quick question guide](http://meta.electronics.stackexchange.com/q/316/2118) that includes a link to common issues in questions, and I think one applies to this: [The XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/154425).

Comment: What are you trying to do in mathematical terms?  abs(abs(X) - Y)?

Comment: @Nick T: |x| < |y|

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Couldn't you just place two equal resistors in series between the two signals? The junction of those resistors would be their average, and has a sign matching the greater side. It could then be compared to zero for amplification.

Comment: This is a good and interesting idea... however I'm not sure if a ground-referenced comparator will be able to distinguish between, say, -50mV and 0V (it might even produce an incorrect result.) It should handle +50mV and 0V, though.

Comment: so bias the resistive divider and comparator to some nominal positive voltage so a reading of -50mV difference is really read as (bias - 50mV)(actual math may be a bit more complicated based on the resistive divider), choose the bias such that for expected values the reading will remain positive.

Comment: Go shopping. Some comparators include 0v in the common-mode range.  Or power the low side of the comparator with a negative rail.  Use a split pullup resistor on the comparator's open-collector output to get the logic swing you want.

Comment: @thomasO, you say you are not sure, but seem to imply that you are correct. This does work, you are correct that you would have to choose your components carefully, but how often do you not have to choose components carefully.

Comment: @Kortuk, I have seen some expensive comparators which can work to -300mV or more below ground, but - they're expensive and/or single source.

Comment: @thomasO, I have used a rail to rail op-amp and made a comparator that worked perfectly for this.

Comment: @Kortuk, For a switching power supply, an op-amp is not feasible, as they do not have suitable speeds except in high cost chips.

Comment: @thomasO, so you have a speed requirement, but in the question do not mention it? This is something that influences an answer. And yes, an op-amp can run at 100 or 400 kHz.

Comment: @kortuk, I figured for a comparator it would not be critical. An op-amp can run at 100kHz or 400kHz, but slew rates are poor and response time is long.

Comment: @thomasO, it is critical to give operator defining details, like frequency. I have already pointed that out though. I will say that yes, an op-amp can operate at that, and well.

Comment: @Kortuk, I would be surprised. Op-amps are not comparators, which is why they are distinct devices. If you can name an op-amp for a reasonable price which outperforms the LM311/LM393 then by all means do.

Comment: @ThomasO, this is a waste of time to discuss in comments, it is not basic operation, you will need compensation. No worries. I would suggest you place any frequency requirements in your question.

Answer (score 1):

Multiple methods making <sub>*electro*</sub>magnetics malleable:

1. Invert the negative voltage with an inverting buffer (op amp).
2. Use one of the following active full-wave rectifiers:

   1. This just works!
      [image]
   2. The other one described in [AoE](http://www.amazon.ca/Art-Electronics-Paul-Horowitz/dp/0521370957) on page 222 (requires bipolar source).
3. When you say *"small signal"*, that tells me you are comparing AC signals riding different biases, which means you can block both biases with blocking caps and compare with a differential amplifier *(eg. "long tailed pair")*. Some diff amps take out bias by default (not related to [CMRR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common-mode_rejection_ratio)).
4. Another idea: scale the negative voltage up to above 0V with a few resistors, as in your first idea, then take care of subsequent bias with math and diff amp resistors.
    [image] 
    V<sub>OUT</sub> will be this:
    [image] 
    Scale R<sub>1</sub> and R<sub>2</sub> such that the op amp positive input is always positive.

Comment: Size is an issue; I'm trying to fit this onto a 1" diameter board, which is realllly small, so I'm not sure about the full wave rectifier. Small signal means low level to me, less than 100mV typically, which makes it difficult to offset.

Comment: You can't fit those circuits onto a board of that size?  If you use one with the resistors all the same value and one other, a DFN op-amp and resistor array is all you need

Answer (score 1):

If you can tolerate a slight current into the circuit (adjustable by modifying the pullup resistors), you can use a diode to offset the voltage:

```
         /-- o ----------o-------------------\
         |   |  ___      -  ___              |
         |   `-|___|-\   `-|___|-\         |\|
         |        .--o-----------)---------|-\  Output
         |        |          .---|         |  >---
         |        |          |   \---------|+/
        --- 5V    V          V             |/|
         -        -          -               |
         |        |          |               |
   /-----o--------)-------o--)---------------/
   |     |        |       |  |   |
  ===    |        |  ___  |  |  .-.
  GND   --- V-    |-|___|-/  \->| |POT
         -        |  SHUNT      | |
         |     // |  Res        '-'
         o-----<|-/              |
         |     LED       ___     |
         \--------------|___|----/
```

You'll need to give the pot the same polarity and ground reference as the shunt resistor, and you'll want to make sure that your diodes have identical forward voltages (use the same diode, and try to find one that characterizes Vf very precisely).

The pullup resistors to 5V should be very large, and the currents through them very small in comparison with the resistances of the pot and shunt resistor and their current values.

(Mega ASCII circuit created with [AACircuit](http://www.tech-chat.de/aacircuit.html))

Comment: [Alternative diagram here, showing zener or diode drop alternatives to LED.](http://i.imgur.com/X7VDE.png)

Answer (score 0):

I had some doubts about your needs. What you want is to "remove" the signal and then find the difference between the signals?

If it is you may acompplish it using an precision rectifier to "remove" the negative signal ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precision_rectifier ) and then an differential amplifier to get the delta between the signals ( http://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/opamp/opamp_5.html )

Comment: I have a negative supply, generated by a buck-boost converter. I want to measure the current through an LED connected to this, which means I'll have to use a current shunt resistor which gives me a negative voltage. I have a potentiometer which outputs a positive voltage. I want to compare the two, without signs.

Comment: @Thomas - You can't just connect the potentiometer to the negative supply?

Comment: @reemrevnivek, The negative supply will have a lot of ripple, and it will only be -2V to -3V (any where between the two.) It drives an LED. Either way, I've now got two negative voltages to compare against each other. How do I do that with a +5V and GND supply only?